# jQuery on click css3 rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get an image to rotate having its transform origin at 50% 50%. is the following correct? It does not seem to work for me.

```
        function slideUp_Menu(){
                    $('.main_nav').slideUp('slow', function(){
                        $("#arrow_up").css({ "-webkit-transform": "rotate(180deg)" });
                        $("#arrow_up").css( "-webkit-transform-origin", "50% 50%");
                    });// $('.tab_wrapper').animate({ marginTop: '193px' }, 500, 'linear');
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add the transitions to your class in css eg:

```
transition: transform 1s ease;
```

then create another class and in there set the transform eg:

```
transform: rotate(10deg);
```

Then I would use jquery to add/remove the class eg:

```
$(document).on('click', 'selector', function() {
 $(this).addClass('class with transform');
});
```

Remember to include all the browser prefixes in your css selectors.

Js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FhXj6/

Answer (score 0):

no man its not correct and its for webkit supporting browsers!

```
    function slideUp_Menu(){
                $('.main_nav').slideUp('slow', function(){
                    $("#arrow_up").css({ "-moz-transform": "rotate(180deg)" });
                    $("#arrow_up").css( "-moz-transform-origin", "50% 50%");
                    $("#arrow_up").css({ "-webkit-transform": "rotate(180deg)" });
                    $("#arrow_up").css( "-webkit-transform-origin", "50% 50%");
                    $("#arrow_up").css({ "transform": "rotate(180deg)" });
                    $("#arrow_up").css( "transform-origin", "50% 50%");
                });// $('.tab_wrapper').animate({ marginTop: '193px' }, 500, 'linear');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it with jQuery but I'd recommend using Greensock for animations:

```
https://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/
```

the performance is far better and stuff like rotating is a breeze. Use .get(0) at the end of your selector and jQuery is a fine partner :)

```
TweenMax.to($("#arrow_up").get(0), {css:{rotation:180}});
```

If you want transform origin look here:

```
https://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/
"transformOrigin – Sets the origin around which all transforms occur. By default, it is in the center of the element ("50% 50%")."
```

Comment: You don't even need to `.get(0)`, TweenMax accepts jQuery wrapped objects / selections.